# How would I resolve an slf4j logback classpath error in Java and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, slf4j

So I'm currently using `Twilio` to send and receive text messages. I'm using `Spring Boot` for the framework of the application, `Gradle` as the build tool, and `VSCode` as the IDE.

It builds successfully when doing a `bootRun`, however my localhost server does not launch and causes the following exceptions in the `DEBUG CONSOLE`.

> Below, I've put some parts of the Debug Console.

Multiple bindings

```
> Task :bootRun
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/james/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21/be4b3c560a37e69b6c58278116740db28832232c/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/james/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

Java IllegialArgumentException

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/james/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21/be4b3c560a37e69b6c58278116740db28832232c/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar).
```

> Here are the implementation statements in my `build.gradle` file that
>   are relevant to what I'm doing

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21'
implementation 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.17.+'
```

> Here are a few things that I have tried to solve the problem:

I've tried putting the following into my gradle file from another StackOverflow question

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
    exclude group: "org.slf4j"
}
```

Running `bootRun` at this point gives a build error and says that those packages don't exist

I've also tried reading through the URL in the `DEBUG CONSOLE`: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings and I did not find anything useful for `Gradle`, as the solutions were only for `Maven`.

At this point I'm not sure what else to do.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot itself comes with a dependency on SLF4J and Logback as its implementation. You need to remove `implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21'` from your configuration.

Comment: It worked and it now runs on my localhost. Thank you!